# Is it possible to delete password generator profiles in KeePass?

Tags: keepass

In KeePass's password generator tool, you can save the current settings in a [password generator profile](http://keepass.info/help/base/pwgenerator.html#profiles). But, I cannot find any interface to delete a profile once it is created. One can *modify* an existing profile by saving over it, but I would like to completely remove a profile I created. This can be done *after exiting KeePass* by manually editing the [local user XML configuration file](http://keepass.info/help/base/configuration.html), but I would like to be able to use a button or menu item in the GUI to remove password generator profiles while KeePass is running, instead of exiting and launching a text editor. How can this be done?

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment on what I could improve in my question to make it better? I thought I gave enough detail on both the problem and what I'm looking for in a solution to make it a decent question.

Comment: "I would like to be able to use a button or menu item in the GUI to remove password generator profiles while KeePass is running, instead of exiting and launching a text editor. How can this be done?" - edit the source code". Of course, then you have to maintain your fork as they update. So it is probably best to request a new feature from the program’s authors.

Comment: You can add custom buttons in KeePass pretty easily and associate a script or action with them, but I don't have the slightest idea what would go *in* such an action at this point. I was hoping someone else might know already.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help, but don't you think that you will get better help at the Keepass forum?  http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a shot. I might get the develeper that way too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer was hiding in plain sight, and I feel stupid for asking the question now. But now that it is here, I feel I should provide an answer for completeness:

There is a nice delete button right next to the save button in the password generator dialog. Simply select the profile you want to delete in the drop-down menu. *As long as you do not make any changes* the name will remain selected in the drop-down, and you can hit the "delete" button to remove the profile.

Probably I had made some change or another after loading the profile, so the delete button was disabled for me when I was looking for it.